# 424 object not found

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code. I am getting a 424 error at the very end. From what I understand, I do not need an object for that piece so I'm very confused as to why i am getting this error.

EDIT: I am getting the error at the very last line.

"Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial.Values"

I have given SrchRng as Range and also a value. Still same line highlighted in debugger.

```
    Dim a As Range
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim oFD As Variant
    Dim AmazonFile As String
    Dim Freight As Range
    Dim OrderNo As Range



    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Amazon File", "*.csv", 1
        .Title = "Choose Text File"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show

        For Each oFD In .SelectedItems
            AmazonFile = oFD
        Next oFD
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    MsgBox AmazonFile

    Set fd = Nothing
    Workbooks.Open (AmazonFile)


    Dim myString As String
    Dim SrchRng



    Do
        Set a = SrchRng.Find("Carrier - Fee", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not a Is Nothing Then a.EntireColumn.Copy
                Loop While a Is Nothing
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial.Values
```

Comment: `SrchRng` never has a value set before this line: `Set a = SrchRng.Find("Carrier - Fee", LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: `SrchRng` is never initialized, and you can't call the `Find` method on an uninitialized variable. Use the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am still getting an error at the very last line: "Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial.Values" via the debugger.

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Answer (score 3):

THe problem is that the PasteSpecial method is not an object

Change this line

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial.Values
```

To this line

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Judging by the incorrect code, the OP probably wants values only, so you will need to add the Paste parameter of `xlPasteValues`.

Comment: @YowE3K Nice observation. Thanks again

Comment: THANK YOU! This made it work. Good looking out @YowE3K